# Perl transformation logic - file processing or DB

Tags: database, perl, file, transformation, preprocessor

I am building the transformation logic for a file that applies certain transformation rules on the fields in the file. Example of such transformation rules are:

- Setting default values for certain fields if they are empty (if col 5 is empty, set it to "Empty")
- Summarizing the file based on certain columns (if file has col1, col2 and col3, summarize file to aggregate col3 for all col1)
- Substituting strings in certain fields (replace all "ax" in col1 with "ay")
- Etc.

From a performance perspective, when dealing with performing these transformations on a large file, is it better to do it using plain file processing (read file line by line, use hashes for summarizing, regexes for other transformations etc.) or load the data into a database table, summarize and apply all transform logic and download it back to a file?

Eg of summarization:

Original file has:

A|B|C|100|200|300

A|B|C|200|100|0

A|X|C|100|100|100

Transformed file has:

A|B|300|300|300

A|X|100|100|100

Comment: Can you clarify what the content of col3 is? Is col3 the same in every row? If you changed one row, would it change the col3 of another row?

Comment: Yes, so the rules would apply to all col3 values in every row.

Comment: How big are the files? How many rows?  How much RAM does the computer have?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data you have given, this problem is well within Perl's grasp without a database:

```
my %data;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($c1, $c2, undef, @cols) = split /\|/, $line, -1;

    $data{"$c1|$c2"}[$_] += $cols[$_] for 0 .. $#cols;
}

print join('|' => $_, @{ $data{$_} }), "\n" for sort keys %data;

__DATA__
A|B|C|100|200|300
A|B|C|200|100|0
A|X|C|100|100|100
```

which prints:

```
A|B|300|300|300
A|X|100|100|100
```

You will of course need to code in the remaining transforms, but this should give you a start.  Even if it turns out you need to access the raw rows more than once, assuming your data is not gigantic, you could load it into a two dimensional array, and then run your passes over it.  Or you could use `Tie::File` to access a very large file without reading it all in.

Comment: And u think this perl code is more efficient than using a database for a file that has million rows?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to code the system both ways and take measurements to decide which is better.